# Statistics joint density function

Tags: statistics

[image]

Tried to solve question, but I am stuck because there is no range for y.

Should I consider range of $y$ like $x \le y \lt \infty$?

Comment: Yes, $y$ ranges to infinity

Comment: Thank you!!could you give me a clue for X/(Y-X)? I have no idea how to approach for (b).

Comment: Have you derived the marginal densities of $Y$ and $X$? If yes, include them in your question, and we will take it from there.

Comment: honestly, I have no idea what you mean. I have learn only outline of this stat material, but instructor gave me way too hard homework. could show me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Marginal distributions:

$f_X(x)=\int_0^\infty f_{XY}(x,y) dy=\int_x^\infty \lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y)dy = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$
$f_Y(y)=\int_0^\infty f_{XY}(x,y) dx=\int_0^y \lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y)dx = \lambda^2 y \exp(-\lambda y)$

So
$f_X(x) f_Y(y) \ne f_{XY}(x,y)$

Now let $Z=X/(Y-X)$

$$
P(Z\le a)=
P(X\le a(Y-X))=
P(X\le aY/(1+a))=\int_0^\infty dy \big(\int_0^{ay/(1+a)} f_{XY}(x,y) dx\big)=\int_0^\infty ay/(1+a) \lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y) dy=a/(1+a)\int_0^\infty y\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y)dy=a/(1+a)
$$
$$
P(Y\le b)=\int_0^b \lambda^2 y \exp(-\lambda y)dy
$$
and
$$
P(Z\le a, Y\le b)=a/(1+a)\int_0^b\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda y)dy
$$
So 
$$
P(Z\le a, Y\le b)=P(Y\le b)P(Z\le a)
$$
and then $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. This is much easier than my instructor's lecture point. Thanks again!